# Pinterest's official OAuth2 flow seemingly returns an invalid access token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, pinterest

I followed the Pinterest's instructions to [authenticate a user](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/authentication/) and after completing step 2 I am holding an access token in my hands. However, when I use this access token to make an API call I get the following response:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 3, "host": "coreapp-devplatform-devapi-179", "generated_at": "Sat, 26 Sep 2015 15:11:35 +0000", "message": "Authorization failed.", "data": null}
```

When I use the [Token Generator](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/access_token/) the API calls succeed. In both cases I tried:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>
```

Any ideas?

---

**Update:** Zack Argyle from Pinterest just tweeted they are working on a fix on their end. https://twitter.com/zackargyle/status/648547619229138944

Comment: Can you try using the [Javascript SDK](http://assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js)? If oauth doesn't work there we can be sure it is an API bug.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Tried both the code and the token flows. My requests work when using a token from the token generator, or a token generated for the app at http://zackargyle.github.io/pinterest-api-demo/

Comment: @ZackArgyle The JavaScript API doesn't work either. PDK.login(...) succeeds but PDK.me(...) gets an invalid response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zack Argyle from Pinterest just tweeted that they deployed a fix which solves the problem I described:
https://twitter.com/zackargyle/status/648602180002312192

Summing it up:

- Follow the instructions on https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/authentication/
- Pass the client_secret not in the first but in the second request
- Use response_type=code in the first request

Comment: Could you help me here, doing the same - https://weblizar.com/pinterest-access-token.php

Answer (score 6):

For those of you who are facing the issue when requesting for access_token in the post request include client_secret too in the 2nd step

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/authentication/

i.e the post params while requesting this end point https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token will be:

**grant_type**             Must be authorization_code

**client_id**              This is your app ID.

**client_secret**          This is your app Secret

**code**                   The authorization code passed to your redirect URI

Comment: Mine doesn't work when I try to use the access_token in a /me request, do you happen to have a solution for that as well?

Comment: @azero0 Are you able to call /me with the token you receive?

Comment: @kunal-nagar Are you able to call /me with the token you receive?

Comment: I am getting the error while posting using curl: "message": "405: Method Not Allowed",
  "type": "http". Please help me, my code is there - https://weblizar.com/pinterest-access-token.php

Comment: "weblizar.com/pinterest-access-token.php" This link is working and I was able to generate access token with it.