# Pinterest API not working as expected

Tags: php, api, curl, pinterest

I'm trying to use the Pinterest API using PHP, but so far it doesn't really work.
I use this guide to get started:

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/authentication/

I got everything working now except for step 3.
The documentation says it's just a simple request to

`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>`

> 3. Making authenticated requests
>
> Finally, once you have an access token, you can make authorized
>   requests on the users behalf using OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens supplied
>   via the Authorization request header or via a request parameter named
>   access_token (supplied as either a form-encoded body parameter or a
>   URI query parameter). The Authorization header is preferred.
>
> For example, you can visit this site on your browser:
>
> https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token= A
>   sample response might look like:
>
> {
>       "data": {
>           "url": "https://www.pinterest.com/ben/", 
>           "first_name": "Ben", 
>           "last_name": "Silbermann", 
>           "id": "4788400174839062"
>       } }

I have an access_token which looks like this:

`AcFFayZKwqXuKVkj1J-0QN1fCob1FAgjuP9-OtFCg_j49UAgogXXXXX`

But everytime I get this message:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 3, "host": "coreapp-devplatform-devapi-181", "generated_at": "Mon, 28 Sep 2015 12:28:38 +0000", "message": "Authorization failed.", "data": null}
```

I use this PHP code to get data from the URL:

```
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => self::userAgent()
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        var_dump($result);
        $errorCode = curl_errno($curl);
        $respCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gone through this same error, but for different endpoint. Try this code

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        $url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token='YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $result = trim(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Can anyone update if this is working for them?

Comment: Why would the OP use your code ? an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @fredy Pinterest deployed a fix: https://twitter.com/zackargyle/status/648602180002312192 You may try again now.

Comment: Thanks @analog-nico that is amazing :-)

Comment: Thanks this helped. It was the CURLOPT_HTTPGET parameter I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798760/pinterests-official-oauth2-flow-seemingly-returns-an-invalid-access-token). It covers the exact same issue you are describing. As far as I can tell right now it seems to be an issue on Pinterest's side. @ZackArgyle from Pinterest's dev team got notified and is working on it I believe.

Comment: I have already found that discussion. The answer is related to another call to Pinterest. It doesn't work with my call. As you can see, the request I make is different as well.

Comment: Do I miss something? Both discussions are talking about the /me endpoint, right?