# 'Authorization Failed' on Pinterest OAuth flow

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests, pinterest

Following the OAuth flow documented [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/?) I seem to do everything right and still get the following json response:

`{'generated_at': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2017 12:47:47 +0000', 'host': 'devplatform-devapi-prod-0a016efb', 'code': 3, 'status': 'failure', 'message': 'Authorization failed.', 'data': None}`

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798760/pinterests-official-oauth2-flow-seemingly-returns-an-invalid-access-token) post about the same issue, but I'm working with the updated docs and all seems to be correct.

I seem to be doing the first step alright, as I get back a valid response including the code returned by the API.

The problem is happening in the second call where I try to exchange the code for a token - then is where it fails

My second call looks like this:

```
self.API_BASE = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/'
.
.
.
code = request.GET['code']
.
.
.
url = '{base}oauth/token'.format(base=self.API_BASE)
data = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': self.client_id,
        'client_secret': self.client_secret,
        'code': code}

response = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
```

The response resulting in the error I posted in the top

Comment: How did you obtain the authorization code? The documentation says *"To get your access code, direct your user to https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/"* Nowhere in your code are you opening a webbrowser for the user.

Comment: I didn't want to make a very long post, obviously I obtained the code, I also verified I received it

Comment: Try `requests.post(url, params=data)`

Comment: Didn't work either, same response :/

Comment: Have you tried with `Session()` ?

Comment: Nope I haven't will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't pass the authorization code properly to the token endpoint.
What is that `code = request.GET['code']` supposed to do ? Can you print such a fetched `code` ?

EDIT: from the pinterest docs, their token endpoint does not seem to be compliant with OAuth 2.0 RFC6749. Token endpoint expects its params passed on query string, while RFC states that they should be passed as application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST data (like you do).
So use `requests.post(url, params=data).json()`

Comment: Its django, I do get the code back from them, checked that

Comment: For example I got `94162c7bc150af5a` when I tried right now